# HTML5 data attribute access using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Which is the difference between code bellow?

```
$("demo").data("title");
```

and,

```
$("demo").attr("data-title");
```

or both are same?

Comment: Both are used for the same purpose. More info : **[Data vs Attr](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7261619/3639582)**

Answer (score 2):

If look at these 2 function from point of working with data-* attributes, them is pretty equal. You can consider data() function as shortcut for attr() function in this case.

But with data() function you can do some more complex things. You can save not only simple strings or some text which usually attached as html attribute, but you can save some custom object. For example you can save some object with data like this:

```
// Attaching custom object to DOM element
var someObj = { id: 1, name: "whatever" };
$("demo").data("someObj", someObj);

// Receiving previously attached object from DOM element
var someObjFromData = $("demo").data("someObj");
```